# Error when formatting a String - ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c)

Tags: python, string, python-2.5

I'm formatting query strings to run on my database.  I am getting a value error when I am trying to format using the % python string formatting method.

The specific error says ValueError: unsupported format character ','  (0x2c) at index where the , occurs after rate.  So inside (locationId, userId, discountId, rate, <- that right there is what is causing the issue for some reason.

```
insertQuery = "INSERT INTO maprateinfo (locationId, userId, discountId, rate, customizedDiscount) VALUES (%i, %i, i%, %f, -1)" % (location, employee, locationDiscount, rate)
```

How can I fix this so the string formats properly?  Using python 2.5.

Comment: You have an `i%` instead of `%i` in your VALUES statement. Is that a typo in your post, or in your original code? Also, can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Welp, thats embarrassing haha.  Thank you.  I don't know how I missed this 10 times.

Comment: You should be **very careful** with this kind of query formatting, by the way. You are better off using a database layer that will handle escaping for you, if you aren't already. This kind of thing can lead to SQL injection attacks, which is a Real Bad Thing.

Comment: I'm aware, thanks, this is all back end stuff that doesn't take any user input so I feel safe doing it here.

Comment: Cool, just making sure. I've submitted this as an answer, to help future internet visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a simple typo in your VALUES statement: `i%` should be `%i`.

Look into using a database layer that will handle doing all the necessary escaping for you (if you aren't already). Otherwise, little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will take over your database.